# JavaScript calculate selected checkbox only

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-blade

I have list of products and i want to calculate their prices when their checkbox is checked, currently my code will calculate all checkboxes including unchecked ones.

`JavaScript`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".bundlechecked").on('click', function () { //div checkbox
            var pp = 0;
            $(".thisPrice").each(function() { //input where price comes from
                if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) 
                {
                    pp += parseFloat(this.value);            
                }         
            });
            console.log(pp);
        });
    });
</script>
```

`Blade (View)`

```
@foreach($bundles as $product)
    <div class="bundlechecked checkbox"> // how we define which item is selected (bundlechecked)
        <label><input type="checkbox" value="{{$product->id}}">
            <div class="product-thumb">
                <div class="image"><img src="{{url('/')}}/images/{{$product->imageOne}}" alt="{{$product->imageOne_alt}}" title="{{$product->title}}" class="img-responsive" /></div>
                <div class="caption">
                <h4>{{$product->title}}</h4>
                @if(!empty($product->newprice))
                <p class="price">
                    <span class="price-new">{{ __('frontend.rp') }} {{ number_format($product->newprice, 0) }}</span>
                    <input type="hidden" class="thisPrice" value="{{$product->newprice}}"> // getting price of selected item
                    <span class="price-old">{{ __('frontend.rp') }} {{ number_format($product->price, 0) }}</span>
                    <span class="saving">
                    - {{number_format(($product->price - $product->newprice) / $product->price * 100, 0) }}%
                    </span>
                </p>
                @else
                <p class="price"> {{ __('frontend.rp') }} {{ number_format($product->price, 0) }} </p>
                <input type="hidden" class="thisPrice" value="{{$product->price}}"> // getting price of selected item
                @endif
                </div>
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

> I commented the code for better understanding

**Any idea?**

Comment: hi @mafortis, i see that thisPrice was hidden

Comment: @KrishnaJonnalagadda yes it is

Comment: you want to calculate hidden values?

Comment: i just try to get price of products that are showing in view on checkbox because my prices are showing in `<p class="price">` tags i decided to make hidden input in order to get those values if there is better way to do that i have nothing against it feel free to share your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

- `onchange` event is better for this purpose
- Key is to get only those price nodes which are checked

```js
var price = 0;
const calculatePrice = function(e) {
  let val = $(e).siblings().first().find('.caption .thisPrice').first().val();
  if(!isNaN(val) && val.length != 0){
      price += parseInt(val);
  }  
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bundlechecked').on('change', function(e){
    price = 0;
    $('.bundlechecked:checked').each((i, e, s) => calculatePrice(e));
    console.clear();
    console.log('Total price =>', price);
  });  
});
```

```css
label { display: block;}
label * { display: inline;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="bundlechecked">
  <div class="product-thumb">                
      <div class="caption">
        <h4>Product One - 10</h4>
        <input type="hidden" class="thisPrice" value="10">
      </div>
  </div>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="bundlechecked">
  <div class="product-thumb">                
      <div class="caption">
        <h4>Product Two - 25</h4>
        <input type="hidden" class="thisPrice" value="25">
      </div>
  </div>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="bundlechecked">
  <div class="product-thumb">                
      <div class="caption">
        <h4>Product Three - 12</h4>
        <input type="hidden" class="thisPrice" value="12">
      </div>
  </div>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="bundlechecked">
  <div class="product-thumb">                
      <div class="caption">
        <h4>Product Four - 30</h4>
        <input type="hidden" class="thisPrice" value="30">
      </div>
  </div>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="bundlechecked">
  <div class="product-thumb">                
      <div class="caption">
        <h4>Product Five - 15</h4>
        <input type="hidden" class="thisPrice" value="15">
      </div>
  </div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".bundlechecked").on('click', function () { //div checkbox
                var pp = 0;
                $(".thisPrice").each(function() { //input where price comes from
                     var checkbox = $(this).parent("label").find("input[type=checkbox]");
                     if (checkbox.prop('checked') && !isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0)
                     {
                         pp = +pp + +parseFloat($(this).val());
                     }
                });
                console.log(pp);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/leonenco/8ojdesz6/26/

Comment: i edited my answer, there is a list of ways how you can try. Check this link: https://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: this.prop is not a function

Comment: giving `0` again

Comment: one second, let me check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201182/discussion-between-serghei-leonenco-and-mafortis).

Comment: @mafortis My answer calculate all fields which are checked.

Comment: @mafortis Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/leonenco/8ojdesz6/25/